# ¿Como transformar variables decimales en fracciones?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando que el programa imprima por pantalla una lista así:

```
lista = [0.5, 5, 0.75]
```

de tal forma que quede [1/2, 5, 3/4]. He probado usando la librería fractions

```
from fractions import Fraction
resultado = []
for i in range(0, len(lista)):
    elem = Fraction(lista[i])
    resultado.append(elem)
```

y en teoría `Fraction()` debería hacerlo pero en cambio lo que me muestra es

> [Fraction(1,2), Fraction(5,1), Fraction(3,4)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que un objeto de tipo `Fraction()` ya no es un número (ni un tipo nativo). Es una instancia de la clase. Por tanto tienes que elegir una forma de *representar* su contenido cuando lo vuelcas con un print.

Si estás intentando imprimir directamente `resultado`, ya que esta variable es una lista, lo que hará Python será imprimir entre corchetes y separados por comas las *representaciones internas* de cada elemento. Para ello usará `repr()` sobre cada objeto de la lista. Es decir, básicamente imprimir `resultado` equivale a imprimir

```
[ repr(elemento) for elemento in resultado ]
```

y `repr()` de una fracción es `Fraction(1,2)`, por ejemplo, en lugar de 1/2 como tú querrías.

La buena noticia es que si en vez de `repr()` usas `str()` obtienes otra representación de la fracción, que sí es la que buscas. Mira:

```
>>> [ str(elemento) for elemento in resultado ]
['1/2', '5', '3/4']
```

Ahora el "inconveniente" es que cada elemento de esta lista es una cadena. Pero no puede ser de otro modo, ya que `1/2` o `3/4` no sería una fracción, sino una división. Python no tiene el tipo "fracción" como nativo (y si lo tuviera necesitaría otro símbolo distinto de `/` para diferenciarlo de la división).

En definitiva. Aunque el tipo `Fraction()` te sirve para contener fracciones de forma exacta, e incluso operar con ellas (`Fraction(1,2) + Fraction(1,3)` te dará correctamente `Fraction(5,6)`), a la hora de mostrarlas tienes que convertirlas a cadenas.

**Edición**

Si, pese a saber que son cadenas, quieres que el usuario que vea el resultado no lo sepa, puedes hacer tu propia función que imprima la lista:

```
def print_list(lst):
   print("[{}]".format(", ".join(str(elem) for elem in lst)))
```

Y, por dar un ejemplo completo, la usarías así:

```
lista = [0.5, 5, 0.75]
from fractions import Fraction
resultado = []
for i in range(0, len(lista)):
    elem = Fraction(lista[i])
    resultado.append(elem)

print_list(resultado)
```

---

```
[1/2, 5, 3/4]
```

Comment: Un truco sucio: `Fraction.__repr__ = Fraction.__str__`

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución emplea [`nsimplify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sympy.simplify.simplify.nsimplify) de SymPy, la librería simbólica de Python:

```
from sympy import nsimplify

lista = [0.5, 5, 0.75]
print([nsimplify(f) for f in lista])
```

Imprime:

```
[1/2, 5, 3/4]
```

`nsimplify` tiene la posibilidad de incluir raíces y números como π, para convertir la respuesta de una calculación a una expresión exacta.